# how to use list comprehension to print a frequency dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say our test case is: `solution([6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10, 10], 1)`

where 1 is the maximum frequency to remain in the list. Logically, this translates to an expected output of `[6, 9]`.

My attempt at a solution:

```py
def solution(data, n): 
    occurrences = dict()

    for _id in data:
        try:
            occurrences[_id] += 1
        except KeyError:
            occurrences[_id] = 1
        print(occurrences)
    return [_id for _ in range(occurrences[_id]) for _id in occurrences if occurrences[_id] <= n]
```

What I am trying to accomplish with the list comprehension at the end is

```py
for key in occurrences:
    if occurrences[key] <= 1:
        for _ in range(occurrences[key]):
            print(key)
```

Unfortunately, this is the output of this test case:

```py
>>> solution([6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10, 10], 1)
{6: 1}
{6: 1, 7: 1}
{6: 1, 7: 2}
{6: 1, 7: 2, 8: 1}
{6: 1, 7: 2, 8: 2}
{6: 1, 7: 2, 8: 3}
{6: 1, 7: 2, 8: 3, 9: 1}
{6: 1, 7: 2, 8: 3, 9: 1, 10: 1}
{6: 1, 7: 2, 8: 3, 9: 1, 10: 2}
[6, 9, 6, 9]
```

Something has to be broken in the list comprehension that is writing `6` and `9` 2 times instead of `range(1)`.

Any idea what that could be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is caused by the `for _ in range(occurrences[_id]`. The reason it causes duplication of the result is that in this comprehension

```
return [_id for _ in range(occurrences[_id]) for _id in occurrences if occurrences[_id] <= n]
```

`_id` is not defined inside the comprehension when you execute `range(occurrences[_id])` so it takes the value that `_id` last had in the function, which in this case is `10` and `occurrences[10]` is 2, so you get 2 copies of each `_id`. Had you used a different variable name inside the comprehension e.g.

```
return [xid for _ in range(occurrences[xid]) for xid in occurrences if occurrences[xid] <= n]
```

you would have seen the issue because you would have got a

> NameError: name 'xid' is not defined

Note you can greatly simplify your code by using a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=collections%20counter#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

def solution(data, n):
    counts = Counter(data)
    return [_id for _id, _count in counts.items() if _count <= n for _ in range(_count)]
```

Comment: the `range()` was actually necessary because the solution requires the numbers returned in the same number they came in, so if my frequency threshold was higher, say 2, and my list was `[1, 1, 2, 2]`, i would actually want the full `[1, 1, 2, 2]` back

Comment: @notacorn ah - that wasn't clear from the question. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: mb, i thought i had it covered by "to remain in the list"

Comment: @notacorn not at all, it was just your example using `n=1` made it look like you just wanted the distinct values in the list which met the criteria rather than all the copies of them. As much mb as yours.

Answer (score 0):

Oh snap, so I randomly decided to try plugging in the for loops the other way around and it worked...

```py
return [_id for _id in occurrences if occurrences[_id] <= n for _ in range(occurrences[_id])]
```

sorry for the trouble!